# Spring - context scan fail with requestfactory (gwt)

Tags: spring, gwt, requestfactory

in a gwt web application i use spring.

if i use in my applicationContext.xml file

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.**"/>
```

my bean is not found, i need to manually declare it in the applicationContext file.

my web.xml file

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
     <servlet-name>gwtRequest</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.RequestFactoryServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>gwtRequest</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/gwtRequest</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
     <welcome-file>welcomeGWT.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Is there any reason why component scan fail?

Locator class

```
public class AccountLocator extends Locator<Account, Long> {

    @Autowired
    private AccountDAO accountDAO;
    ...
}
```

Spring service locator

```
public class SpringServiceLocator implements ServiceLocator {

    @Override
    public Object getInstance(Class<?> clazz) {
        HttpServletRequest request = RequestFactoryServlet.getThreadLocalRequest();
        ServletContext servletContext = request.getSession().getServletContext();
        ApplicationContext context =       WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
    return context.getBean(clazz);
}
```

}

Server layer

```
@Service
public class AccountServiceImpl implements AccountService{
    @Autowired
    private AccountDAO accountDAO;
...
}
```

Dao layer

```
@Repository
public class AccountDAOImpl implements AccountDAO{
...
}
```

Comment: Could you please post your bean source code. I think you have not specified @Component or (@Service,...) annotation there

Comment: @Autowired private AccountDAO accountDAO; in the AccountLocator will not work. The locator instance is created by GWT so injection doesn't work. Instead you can use the same approach as in the ServiceLocator class.

Comment: ok i understand gwt don't do the injection but i don't undersand how to use same approach then ServiceLocator... i can't add it to AccountLocator

Comment: You could copy (or re-use) the getInstance() method from the SpringServiceLocator in the AccountLocator to get an instance of your AccountDao.